How to merge dictionaries contained in a Pandas dataframe as a groupby operation
Let us consider a pandas dataframe df containing dictionaries in one of its columns (column mydict):

      mystring    mydict 
0     a           {'key1': 'value1'} 
1     a           {'key2': 'value2'}
2     b           {'key2': 'value2'}


I would like to "merge" the dictionaries as part of a groupby operation, e.g. df.groupby('mystring')['mydict'].apply(lambda x: merge_dictionaries(x)).
The expected output for mystring 'a' would be: {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
The usual way of combining dictionaries is to update an existing dictionary (dict1.update(dict2)), so I am not sure how to implement this here.
Here is the code snippet to create the dataframe used in this example:
mycolumns = ['mystring', 'mydict']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = mycolumns)
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(['a', {'key1':'value1'}],mycolumns).T)
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(['a', {'key2':'value2'}],mycolumns).T)
df = df.append(pd.DataFrame(['b', {'key3':'value3'}],mycolumns).T)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

EDIT: a way to achieve a similar result without using groupby would be to iterate over the mystring and then update the dictionary:
merged_dict = {}
for mystring in df.mystring.unique():
    for mydict in df[df.mystring==mystring]['mydict']:
        print(mydict)
        merged_dict.update(mydict)

EDIT 2: append is no longer available in pandas 2.0.1. Here is the alternate snippet to create the example dataframe using concat:
mycolumns = ['mystring', 'mydict']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = mycolumns)
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(['a', {'key1':'value1'}],mycolumns).T])
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(['a', {'key2':'value2'}],mycolumns).T])
df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(['b', {'key3':'value3'}],mycolumns).T])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)


Try:
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

out = df.groupby("mystring", as_index=False)["mydict"].agg(lambda x: reduce(or_, x))

print(out)

Prints:
  mystring                                mydict
0        a  {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
1        b                    {'key3': 'value3'}


Or:
out = df.groupby("mystring", as_index=False)["mydict"].agg(
    lambda x: reduce(dict.__or__, x)
)


Or:
out = df.groupby("mystring", as_index=False)["mydict"].agg(
    lambda x: reduce(lambda a, b: {**a, **b}, x)
)
print(out)


Or:
out = df.groupby("mystring", as_index=False)["mydict"].agg(
    lambda x: reduce(lambda a, b: dict(**a, **b), x)
)
print(out)


Thanks again for your answer! reduce seems like a very powerful tool. I am still struggling to understand the syntax in your first two solutions. Could you please explain what is achieved by using dict.__or__?

@Sheldon In newer versions of Python you can do {'key1':'val1'} | {'key2':'val2'} to merge the dictionaries (note, the | is or-operator)
